# Select few elements of document in single query

Tags: javascript, marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to get some selected elements from the documents satisfying a cts.Query. I am using javascript on MarkLogic Documents are like this -

```
<a:root xmlns:a = 'some-ns'>
    <a:id>some-id</a:id>
    <a:some-element1/>
    <a:some-element2/>
    <a:some-element3/>
    .
    .
    <a:number field='field1'>3</a:number>
    <a:number field='field2'>4</a:number>
    .
    .
</a:root>
```

I want to get `a:id`, `a:number` elements and `field` attribute of `a:number` in a single query.

I tried using -

```
cts.valueTuples(
    [
      cts.elementReference(fn.QName(a, 'id')),
      cts.elementAttributeReference(fn.QName(a, 'number'), xs.QName('field')),
      cts.elementReference(fn.QName(a, 'number'))      
    ],
  [],
  cts.andQuery(
      [
        <query1>,
        <query2>
      ]
    )
)
```

But this is giving me all the combinations of results for the 3 queries in value tuples (something like cartesian product).

How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable the appropriate word position indexes, you could try the `ordered` option:

> Include co-occurrences only when the value from the first lexicon
>   appears before the value from the second lexicon. Requires that word
>   positions be enabled for both lexicons.

I don't think it will prevent cross-products, but it should at least result in less of them.

Though, there is nothing wrong with executing multiple calls to `cts.values` and `cts.valueTuples`. You could do three calls, and ask for uri-value combinations (using `cts.uriReference()`), and use the uri to correlate between the results..

HTH!